# Equation of intersection of two cones

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The equations of two cones are given;

$(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2=\frac {(z-z_{0})^2}{m^2}$

and

$(x-x_{1})^2+(y-y_{1})^2=\frac {(z-z_{1})^2}{m^2}$

How to find the equations of intersections

1) When the intersection is an ellipse?

2) When the intersection is a hyperbola?

Comment: Subtracting one cone equation from the other we get a plane of the form $ax+by+cz=1$ which cuts each cone along a hyperbola. Constants can be expressed in terms of four constants as semi vertical angles $( \alpha_! , \alpha_2) $ and inclinations of the plane  to each cone  axis $ (\gamma_1,\gamma_2).$

Answer (score 4):

As the two cones have the same aperture and parallel axes, their intersection is a hyperbola if both vertices are external to the other cone, and is an ellipse if a vertex is inside the other cone. Finally, if a vertex is on the surface of the other cone, then the cones are tangent and their intersection is a line.

[image]

In any case, by subtracting one equation from the other one you will find the equation of the plane containing the intersection.